# Defining custom color palette for custom map in HighMaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have drawn a custom map in Inkscape and generated the JSON SVG output. I modified the JSON so each region of the map is its own  series.

When I instantiate the map using the default color palette, it loads very quickly in IE 11 and Edge. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a2bukkq/8/) is the fiddle.

However, when I define a custom color palette using the colors property of the highcharts object or setting the color property in the map data, the colors do not appear until regions are hovered over. Also, the legend indicates all regions are black despite the custom color palette. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9a2bukkq/7/) is the fiddle.

```
$(function () {
    var md = mapData[0].data;
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        title : { text : 'COCOMs' },        
        colors: ["#6cc2c8ff", "#3a784cff", 
                 "#c4b9c9ff", "#d3eafaff", 
                 "#afd5acff", "#e4cf8cff"],
        series: jQuery.map(md, function(element, index) {
            var seriesElement = {
                type: 'map',
                joinBy: 'name',
                name: element.name,
                data: new Array({name:element.name, value:index}),
                mapData: new Array(element),
                _colorIndex: index
            };
            return seriesElement;
        })
    });
});
```

Something different happens in Chrome and FireFox, but it still does not seem right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your colors are not valid color hex codes. They are all 8 digits, but need to be 6 digits. With valid color hex codes, everything works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/9a2bukkq/10/

Comment: They are valid hex codes, but they include the alpha (RGBa). I didn't notice it was there, nor realize HighCharts/HighMaps couldn't handle it. Got it working now after removing the alpha information. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Not valid in terms of CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/tdxe2mmo/ To use rgba, use `rgba(red, green, blue, opacity)` format.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify: aRGB hex codes are not valid in this context, or in the context of CSS color declarations. :)